# HorizontalScrollView scrolls vertically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, horizontalscrollview

I have a `HorizontalscrollView` inside a horizontal `LinearLayout` and for some reason I can only scroll vertically. Somewhere I read that the it needs to be within a horizontal `LinearLayout` but it still didn't fix the problem. Help appreciated a lot. Thanks..

Here's the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#deefed"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Textview"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="edittext"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:maxLines="1" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's your `EditText` that scrolls vertically, not the `HorizontalScrollView`.

If you want that the text goes only horizontally change it this way:

```
<EditText
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:digits="0123456789."
     android:ems="10"
     android:hint="edittext"
     android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:maxLines="1" />
```

By adding

```
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:singleLine="true"
```

It will stay in single row and it will scroll horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correct, you want to scroll your text in EditText horizontally. I think you do not need a horizontal scroll view for that and the problem could be solved by just using **android:singleLine="true"** in EditText.

android:maxLines is so confusing, because it does something very different. It only sets the vertical view bound of EditText to show as many lines at a time as it's value, like android:maxLines = "5" would show 5 lines at a time in the EditText view.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#deefed"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Textview"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:digits="0123456789."
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="edittext"
            android:inputType="number|numberDecimal"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </Spinner>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```